# How can I draw a curve based on expression via ironpython?

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

In my scatterplot visualization, I added a "Curve from Data Table" with a custom expression that references variables from this data table. How can I do this via ironpython?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all revolves around the FittingModels module.
Assuming it is a ScatterPlot:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import *
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals.FittingModels import *

# Get visual v by name
# (alternatively input v as input parameter of type Visualization)
vss=Document.ActivePageReference.Visuals
v=None
for vv in vss:
    if vv.Title=='the title of your chart': v=vv
# This should already be a ScatterPlot, just cast it
my_chart=v.As[ScatterPlot]()

# Get hold of the FittingModels for this chart
fitting_models=my_chart.FittingModels
# If you want to remove all
#fitting_models.Clear()

# Define the new curve from data table
data_table=Document.Data.Tables["the name of your data table"]
curve_name = 'the name you give to the new curve'
curve_expression = 'the curve expression'

# If the curve already exists, do nothing, otherwise add it
exists=False
for ff in fitting_models:
    if ff.Curve.DisplayName==curve_name:
        exists=True

if exists==False:
    new_curve = fitting_models.AddCurve(data_table,curve_expression)
    new_curve.Curve.CustomDisplayName=curve_name
```